# Flutter type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool' error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

I want to browse through the documents with for on Firestore and query whether there is a value equal to the e-mail address I entered with the controller structure. For this I followed a code like below. But it gives me the error mentioned in the title. What can I do about it?

My Code:

```
masterEmailGet() {
  var _usersDoc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Master').get();
  for (var eleman in _usersDoc.docs) {
    if (eleman.data()['masterEmail'] == _emailController.text) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
```

Called:

```
InkWell(
   onTap: () { 
      if (masterEmailGet()) {
         _auth.signIn(_emailController.text, _passController.text).then((value) {
         return Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => BottomNavBar())));
        });
       }
   },
```

I've done a lot of research on the internet but haven't found a working solution.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: add the code where `masterEmailGet` is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `masterEmailGet` returns a `Future`, you need to `await` for its call in `if`. Also add `async` in the function body `masterEmailGet() async { /* */ }`.

```dart
onTap: () async { 
    if (await masterEmailGet()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: now it worked but gave an error on emulator on new screen. Error: Type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic> in type casting See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

Comment: `eleman.data()` might be `null` as well. Add a null-check there or use bang operator `!`.